# How to format a float so that the digit before the separator is not shown, if it is 0

Tags: java, string-formatting

I currently something like this:

```
float someFloat = -0.42f;
String.format("%.2f", someFloat);
```

This will print as:

```
-0.42
```

I would like to save space, since this is output to a GUI with limited horizontal space. So instead I would like it to print:

```
-.42
```

and similarly for a positive value, e.g.:

```
.52
```

For values a with |a|>1, it should still print the digit before the separator, e.g.:

```
42.42
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DecimalFormat` instead, this works for greater than 1 value as well

```
float someFloat = -0.42f;
String withoutLeadingZero = new DecimalFormat(".##").format(someFloat);
System.out.println(withoutLeadingZero);
```